# Electromagnetic tensor in cylindrical coordinates from scratch

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, metric-tensor

I want to calculate the electromagnetic tensor components in cylindrical coordinates. Suppose I did not know that those components are given in Cartesian coordinates by
$$(F^{\mu \nu})=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & E_x & E_y & E_z \\
-E_x & 0 & B_z & -B_y \\
-E_y & -B_z & 0 & B_x \\ 
-E_z & B_y & -B_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I want to derive the result in the same manner I did in the Cartesian coordinates case, i.e., using that $F^{ \mu \nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu$, where $A^\alpha=(V,\vec{A})$, $\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$ and $\vec{E} = -\nabla V - \partial \vec{A} / \partial t$. Using the formulas for curl and gradient in cylindrical coordinates, we find
$$
\vec{E} = - \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial t} \right)\hat{r} \
- \left( \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} + \frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial t} \right)\hat{\phi}
- \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial t} \right)\hat{z} 
$$
and
$$
\vec{B} = \left( \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial \phi} - \frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial z} \right)\hat{r} \
+\left(\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} \right)\hat{\phi} \
+\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial (r A_\phi)}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r} \right)\hat{z}. \
$$
The invariant interval is given by $ds^2 = -dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 d\phi^2 + dz^2$, (with $c=1$). Therefore, the metric tensor reads
$$(g_{\mu \nu})=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
and its inverse is
$$(g^{\mu \nu})=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/r^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Which implies $\partial^0 = -\partial_0$,  $\partial^1 = \partial_1$,  $\partial^2 = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_2$ and $\partial^3 = \partial_3$.

So, for example,
$$
F^{ 01} = \partial^0 A^1 - \partial^1 A^0 = -\partial_0 A^1 - \partial_1 A^0 = -\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = E_r,
$$
which is reassuring.
Now,
$$
F^{02} = \partial^0 A^2 - \partial^2 A^0 = -\partial_0 A^2 - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_2 A^0 = -\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial t}-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}.
$$
However, I cannot identify this quantity with any component of the electric field. This last expression looks almost like $E_\phi$, except for an extra $\frac{1}{r}$ multiplying $\partial V / \partial \phi$. What went wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there is a mismatch between the vector basis that you are using to write the 4-vector potential and the ones you are considering for your metric, which are not unitary. The standard cylindrical coordinate basis should have a Minkwoski metric, since we don't really have curvature in this case. The only difference is then a $1/r$ factor in the $\phi$ component.

Therefore, in order to be consistent, you need to replace $A^2 \rightarrow \frac{A_{\phi}}{r}$.  Then, you will see that $F^{02}=\frac{E_{\phi}}{r}$, which, again, is consistent with your metric.

Comment: For people curious why this is, the natural basis vector for the angular coordinate has length $\langle e_\theta, e_\theta\rangle = r^2$, which is the definition of the metric components. However physicists love to work with unit vectors and so almost always pull out the size of the basis explicitly $e_\theta = r \hat{\theta}$. This leaves the usual basis employed by physicists as neither the naturally covariant or contra-variant basis, and as such the components of vectors, both raised and lowered, will be off by an $r$ somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you were like me who thought for two minutes before understanding [*Ben*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/126749/ben)'s answer, here is a longer but maybe more detailed explanation, and hopefully, more straightforward to understand.

Let us first rephrase the answer in a more detailed fashion.

The unit bases in cylindrical coordinates, denoted by $(\hat{r},\hat{\phi},\hat{z})$ above, are the non-coordinate basis. This is discussed clearly in, for instance, the textbook of Schutz *A First Course in General Relativity*, by the end of Chapter 5. To be specific, these bases (as well as the components) do not transform as tensor (eg. vector or 1-form). By employing the same convention, let us denote the *correct* coordinate basis one-forms by ${\vec{e}}^1, {\vec{e}}^2, {\vec{e}}^3$.
These bases can be obtained by the transformation rule of tensors. For instance, explicit calculations give
$${\vec{e}}^2=\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial {x'}^\mu}{\vec{e}'}^\mu =\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}{\vec{e}}^x+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}{\vec{e}}^y=-\frac1r\sin\phi {\vec{e}}^x+\frac1r\cos\phi {\vec{e}}^y=-\frac1r\sin\phi \hat{x}+\frac1r\cos\phi \hat{y}=\frac1r \hat{\phi}$$
for basis one-form, and similarly, one finds
$${\vec{e}}_2=-r\sin\phi \hat{x}+r\cos\phi \hat{y}=r \hat{\phi}$$
for basis vector, where we have made use of the explicit form of coordinate transformation $x=r\cos\phi, y=r\sin\phi$ and the fact ${\vec{e}}^x={\vec{e}}_x=\hat{x}, {\vec{e}}^y={\vec{e}}_y=\hat{y}$, namely, the coordinate bases in Cartesian coordiante are unit vectors.

Now, a vector can be written down in both bases, coordinate one and non-coordinate one as
$$\vec{A}=A^1 {\vec{e}}_1+A^2{\vec{e}}_2+A^3{\vec{e}}_3=A_r\hat{r}+A_\phi\hat{\phi}+A_z\hat{z}$$
Therefore we have $A^2=\frac{A_\phi}{r}$.
We note that the question at hand is about looking for a relation between $F^{02}$ and $E_\phi$, the latter is defined as the component in the front of the relevant unit basis vector, namely, $\hat{\phi}$. Before proceed further, we emphasize that $A_\phi$ or $E_\phi$ is NOT a component of any *real* vector in the context of tensorial algebra.

By putting all the pieces together, in co-moving frame (see comments below) one finds
$$E^{2}= F^{02} = \partial^0 A^2 - \partial^2 A^0 = -\partial_0 A^2 - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_2 A^0 = -\frac1r\frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial t}-\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi}=\frac{E_\phi}{r},$$
namely, everything is indeed consistent.
As mentioned, the about part has been pointed out in Ben's answer.

However, when I explored a bit further regarding the original question proposed by [*Thiago*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/42249/thiago), the following question was raised.

In terms of the scalar and vector potentials, the electric field and magnetic induction are defined as rank-two tensors. These quantities, for instance $F^{02}\equiv \partial^0A^2-\partial^2A^0$ are eventually compared against vectors, for instance, $E^2$. Even though these components are shown to be identical for a particular case, the equalities are not expected to hold in any coordinate system. Therefore, one might wonder if there is a more serious problem: why such a comparison is meaningful at all?

To solve the second issue, let us note that a more general definition (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9803033) for instance) of electromagnetic fields in terms of $F^{\mu\nu}\equiv \partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu$ are
$$E^i=F^{ i \alpha}u_\alpha,$$
$$B^i= {^*F}^{i\beta}u_\beta$$
where ${^*F}^{\alpha\beta}\equiv \frac12\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}F_{\beta\delta}$ and $\varepsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor.
The mathematical aspect is obvious, one has to contract a rank-two tensor in order to obtain a vector.
The physical interpretation of this choice is the following.
It implies that one has to choose an observer whose world line is described by the four-velocity, the definition of the electromagnetic fields has to be implemented from his point of view.
Of course, the four-velocity $u_\alpha$ falls back to $(1,0,0,0)$ in the co-moving frame of the observer and therefore from his viewpoint, the traditional definition is restored.